# Last parameter in call to unmanaged dll always null

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unmanaged

I am calling an unmanaged dll from c#.  If I pass the output char array as the last parameter, it is null in the c++ code.  However, if I pass it as the first parameter it is good as are all the other parameters (I haven't tried putting it as the second or third parameter).

This is the signature that fails:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) processBuffer(const char *token, const char *inBuffer, const long inBufferSize, char *outBuffer);
```

The c# code is -
Wrapper class:

```
[DllImport(@"<path to dll>\<dllname>.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static class NativeCalls
{
    public static extern void processBuffer(string token, char[] inBuffer, long inBufferSize, [In, Out] char[] outBuffer);
}
```

Call to unmanaged dll:

```
// token, inBuffer and inBuffer size defined above
char[] outBuffer = new char[outBufferSize];
NativeCalls.processBuffer(token, inBuffer, inBufferSize, outBuffer);
```

With this call, outBuffer comes in to the c++ code as 0x00000000 (null). The rest of the parameters are correct.

If I change the code so outBuffer is the first parameter (in all necessary locations), it arrives in the c++ not null, can be written to without error, and shows valid data when inspected after the call return.

Clearly, something is wrong... I just don't know what.  Any and all help greatly appreciated!

Comment: C++ long == C# int.  You get null in the C++ code because it is reading the upper 32-bits of the long variable.  Just fix the declaration.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it.  Thanks Hans!